# How do I keep the items from hiding in connected sortable lists inside scrolling panes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a couple of jQuery sortable list connected to each other. Since both lists are quite long, they are inside divs that are set to scroll on overflow. Dragging from one and dropping on another works, but the item is not visible during the process. It becomes invisible when it tries to leave the scrolling section.

Here's the list:

[image]

and here I'm dragging an item to the outside and it starts to be hidden by the outside of the scrollable pane:

[image]

Here's a video of the issue: https://vimeo.com/40218644

Any ideas how to make that item not being hidden by the rest of the page?

Comment: For that you should remove overflow hidden from scrollers contaner, maby it should be done on drag event, but after that you will need to cut all elements inside container to give them look like they were before. Maby you can remove only overflow-x... But this will give you more and more problems. Other solution is to make a dropable element preview in the body and drag it there.